# Recursion Tree with Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

I created the following tree:

[image]

But now I want it to be vertical like this:

[image]

For creating the horizontal one I used the following code:

```py
from turtle import *

def tree(length,order):
    if length < (length/order):
           return       
    forward(length)      
    left(45)         
    tree(length * 0.5,length/order)      
    right(90)         
    tree(length * 0.5,length/order)      
    left(45)          
    backward(length)       
    return              
tree (200, 5)
```

Now, I am trying the following code to create it vertically but it stuck (I think) at line *right(45)* line:

```py
def tree(length,order):
    if length < (length/order):
           return       
    rt(-90)
    forward (length)
    right(45)
    tree(length * 0.5,length/order)      
    left(225)         
    tree(length * 0.5,length/order)      
    left(90)          
    backward(length) 
    return

tree (200,5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import turtle

def tree(t,length,order):
    if length < (length/order):
           return       
    t.forward(length)      
    t.left(45)         
    tree(t,length * 0.5,length/order)      
    t.right(90)         
    tree(t,length * 0.5,length/order)      
    t.left(45)          
    t.backward(length)       
    return

screen = turtle.Screen ( ) 
tip = turtle.Turtle() 
tip.shape ("turtle") 
tip.speed (1)   
  
tip.left(90)  # vertical start
tree (tip, 200, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be as simple as a one-line fix:

```
mode('logo')
```

Among other things, `'logo'` mode changes 0 degrees to be towards the top of the screen insted of the right:

```
from turtle import *

def tree(length, order):
    if length >= length / order:
        forward(length)
        left(45)
        tree(length / 2, length / order)
        right(90)
        tree(length / 2, length / order)
        left(45)
        backward(length)

mode('logo')

tree(200, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Hey, look!*** **Here is a Recursion Tree program built into the built-in `turtle` package:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""      turtle-example-suite:

             tdemo_tree.py

Displays a 'breadth-first-tree' - in contrast
to the classical Logo tree drawing programs,
which use a depth-first-algorithm.

Uses:
(1) a tree-generator, where the drawing is
quasi the side-effect, whereas the generator
always yields None.
(2) Turtle-cloning: At each branching point
the current pen is cloned. So in the end
there are 1024 turtles.
"""
from turtle import Turtle, mainloop
from time import clock

def tree(plist, l, a, f):
    """ plist is list of pens
    l is length of branch
    a is half of the angle between 2 branches
    f is factor by which branch is shortened
    from level to level."""
    if l > 3:
        lst = []
        for p in plist:
            p.forward(l)
            q = p.clone()
            p.left(a)
            q.right(a)
            lst.append(p)
            lst.append(q)
        for x in tree(lst, l*f, a, f):
            yield None

def maketree():
    p = Turtle()
    p.setundobuffer(None)
    p.hideturtle()
    p.speed(0)
    p.getscreen().tracer(30,0)
    p.left(90)
    p.penup()
    p.forward(-210)
    p.pendown()
    t = tree([p], 200, 65, 0.6375)
    for x in t:
        pass
    print(len(p.getscreen().turtles()))

def main():
    a=clock()
    maketree()
    b=clock()
    return "done: %.2f sec." % (b-a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    msg = main()
    print(msg)
    mainloop()
```

#### Now, focus on the `make_tree` function:

```
def maketree():
    p = Turtle()
    p.setundobuffer(None)
    p.hideturtle()
    p.speed(0)
    p.getscreen().tracer(30,0)
    p.left(90) # HERE! They turned left by 90 degrees!
    p.penup()
    p.forward(-210)
    p.pendown()
    t = tree([p], 200, 65, 0.6375)
    for x in t:
        pass
    print(len(p.getscreen().turtles()))
```

---

From that built-in `tree.py` file, simply removing some code without adding any can get you:

```
from turtle import Turtle

def tree(plist, l, a, f):
    if l > 3:
        lst = []
        for p in plist:
            p.forward(l)
            q = p.clone()
            p.left(a)
            q.right(a)
            lst.append(p)
            lst.append(q)
        for x in tree(lst, l * f, a, f):
            yield None

p = Turtle()
p.hideturtle()
p.getscreen().tracer(30,0)
p.left(90)
for x in tree([p], 120, 65, 0.6375):
    pass
```

Output:

[image]

What's different from the above method and your current method is that we get to see each level of branches grow altogether, instead of waiting for a single route to finish every time.